# Google Maps SDK doesnt return directions

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've installed Google Maps SDK for iOS thinking that I would get the directions between two places, like , [the web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?hl=es#directions) but following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?hl=es#directions) what it seems is that it just opens the Google Maps app, which can also be done without the SDK.
Am I understanding it wrong or the Google Maps SDK only offers open the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends exactly what you mean and want by "directions".

The Google Maps SDK for iOS does not itself do any sort of directions.

What you can do is use the [Google Maps Directions web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to obtain information, then use that information to create a `GMSPolyline` which then can be rendered atop your in-app map. So basically it can show the line between point A and B, which is some level of directions, but may or may not be what you're wanting. [Here's a YouTube video from Google that shows how to do this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg), and some [sample code from Google's Mano Marks](https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync).

But if what you want are turn-by-turn directions, spoken directions, etc., no, the SDK cannot do that; you have to launch the external Google Maps app.